# getting information out of an array with key/value pairs

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I have the following snippet of code that is creating the following array...

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  foreach($row as $key => $val) {
    $x[$key] = $val;
  }
  $results[] = $x;
}
```

Results in the follow array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [cap_login] => master [cap_pword] => B-a411dc195b1f04e638565e5479b1880956011badb73361ca ) )
```

Basically I want to extract the cap_login and cap_pword values for testing. For some reason I can't get it!
I've tried this kind of thing:

```
echo $results[$cap_login];
```

but I get the error

```
Undefined variable: cap_login
```

Can someone put me right here?
Thanks.

Comment: `$results[0]["cap_login"]`?

Comment: You don't need the inner `foreach`. Just do `$results[] = $row`. Also, I assume you meant to write `white ($row = $stmt->fetch())`.

Comment: thanks folks. all these answers are good. i'm amazed how fast people answer on this site and the quality of the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cap_login is in an array within $results so you would have to do `$results[0]['cap_login']`

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do the following:

```
echo $x[0]['cap_login'] . '<br />';
echo $x[0]['cap_pword'];
```

The reson `$results[$cap_login]` wont work is because there isn't a variable called `$cap_login`, there is a string called cap login. In addition, there isn't a key in $results called $cap_login. There is a value in $results called 'cap_login'